# Writing flattened arrays to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am trying to write the values in a pandas dataframe to a csv file. The sample code is given below. The computations like mean, multiplying with np.pi are just illustrative (the actual work generates ndarrays for some parameters).

My problem is that the flattened ndarrays are being written on to the same row of the csv file. I would like them to be written on to separate rows and then begin the row of the next parameter. For instance after writing values of parameter2 to rows write the value of parameter3.

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_list = []
parm_list = []
temp_dict = {}

# data 

for i in range(1000):
    n = np.random.randint(1,100)
    data_list.append(n)
data_array = np.array(data_list)

data = np.split(data_array,100)

# parameters
for i in range(10):
    parameter1 = np.mean(data[i])
    parameter2 = data[i].reshape(5,2)*np.pi
    parameter2_flat = parameter2.flatten()
    parameter3 = np.median(data[i])
       
    temp_dict = dict([('parameter1', parameter1), ('parameter2', parameter2_flat),('parameter3', parameter3)])
    parm_list.append(temp_dict)
parm_df = pd.DataFrame(parm_list)
transposed_df = parm_df.T
transposed_df.to_csv('parameter.csv')
```

[image: transposed_df when this code is run]

[image: parameter.csv when the code is run]

In this output the parameter2 values are being written on the same row of the data frame and also of the csv file. I would like the parameter 2 values written one below the other (ie in different rows of the data frame and csv file). The parameter3 value has to be written on the next row after all the parameter2 values have been written.

Comment: does transposed_df.to_csv('parameter.csv', sep='\n') works or just add \n at the end of file

Comment: not sure I got youe question right but try code above and let me know

Comment: @pippo1980 Thank you for the response. But I would to have the values written in a different format. I have edited the question and added screenshots and comments to clarify the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

using:

`transposed_df.to_csv('parameter.csv', sep='\n')`

in line 40

gives

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
parameter1
49.6
32.9
58.7
50.1
32.2
35.2
44.7
52.8
50.1
53.3
parameter2
"[229.33626371  31.41592654 135.0884841  282.74333882 125.66370614
 263.8937829    6.28318531  34.55751919 172.78759595 276.46015352]"
"[201.06192983   3.14159265  75.39822369  72.25663103 116.23892818
 204.20352248  50.26548246  65.97344573 194.77874452  50.26548246]"
"[ 91.10618695  75.39822369  65.97344573 298.45130209 279.60174617
 179.07078125 216.7698931  144.51326207 191.63715187 301.59289474]"
"[128.8052988   12.56637061 113.09733553  37.69911184 238.76104167
 150.79644737 307.87608005 279.60174617 292.16811678  12.56637061]"
"[ 59.69026042 113.09733553  25.13274123  65.97344573  34.55751919
 282.74333882  78.53981634 153.93804003   3.14159265 194.77874452]"
"[241.90263433 185.35396656  43.98229715  56.54866776 282.74333882
  69.11503838 100.53096491  50.26548246  34.55751919  40.8407045 ]"
"[188.49555922 172.78759595 270.17696821 219.91148575  62.83185307
  78.53981634 179.07078125 157.07963268  72.25663103   3.14159265]"
"[270.17696821 144.51326207 175.9291886   62.83185307  12.56637061
 106.81415022 235.61944902 179.07078125 279.60174617 191.63715187]"
"[103.67255757  81.68140899 248.18581963 122.52211349 210.48670779
 282.74333882 219.91148575  87.9645943   69.11503838 147.65485472]"
"[ 94.24777961 295.30970944  78.53981634 219.91148575  75.39822369
  65.97344573 163.36281799 219.91148575 175.9291886  285.88493148]"
parameter3
49.0
23.5
59.0
44.5
23.0
20.0
52.5
56.5
43.0
54.0
```

while using :

```
for i in transposed_df:
    print(transposed_df[i])
    transposed_df[i].to_csv('parameter_bis.csv',  mode='a', sep='\n')
```

instead of line 40

gives:

```
0
parameter1
47.9
parameter2
"[232.47785637 122.52211349 131.94689145 163.36281799 182.21237391
  62.83185307 160.22122533 125.66370614 122.52211349 201.06192983]"
parameter3
46.5

1
parameter1
62.2
parameter2
"[ 94.24777961 169.64600329 197.92033718 307.87608005 172.78759595
 223.0530784  276.46015352  37.69911184 185.35396656 289.02652413]"
parameter3
61.0

2
parameter1
51.9
parameter2
"[ 37.69911184 185.35396656  56.54866776 210.48670779 307.87608005
  91.10618695 182.21237391 251.32741229 251.32741229  56.54866776]"
parameter3
58.5

3
parameter1
63.6
parameter2
"[204.20352248 160.22122533 160.22122533 273.31856086 260.75219025
  62.83185307  59.69026042 235.61944902 301.59289474 279.60174617]"
parameter3
70.0

4
parameter1
58.2
parameter2
"[311.01767271  12.56637061 119.38052084 270.17696821  65.97344573
  12.56637061 238.76104167 276.46015352 229.33626371 292.16811678]"
parameter3
74.5

5
parameter1
32.5
parameter2
"[216.7698931  175.9291886   75.39822369  31.41592654  84.82300165
 109.95574288  15.70796327  31.41592654 172.78759595 106.81415022]"
parameter3
30.5

6
parameter1
51.4
parameter2
"[210.48670779  31.41592654 213.62830044 169.64600329   3.14159265
 301.59289474 282.74333882 204.20352248 131.94689145  65.97344573]"
parameter3
59.5

7
parameter1
45.1
parameter2
"[191.63715187 245.04422698 207.34511514 229.33626371  87.9645943
 131.94689145  62.83185307  28.27433388 182.21237391  50.26548246]"
parameter3
50.0

8
parameter1
61.5
parameter2
"[172.78759595 125.66370614 191.63715187 276.46015352 125.66370614
 307.87608005 257.61059759 298.45130209  97.38937226  78.53981634]"
parameter3
58.0

9
parameter1
52.5
parameter2
"[113.09733553  21.99114858 135.0884841  304.7344874  226.19467106
  21.99114858 179.07078125 263.8937829  273.31856086 109.95574288]"
parameter3
50.0
```

let us know if it is what you were looking for, I cannot really visualize from your question the desidered output